# Definition of Closed Set (in topology vs analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In Rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis), he defines a **closed set** as

> E is closed if every limit point of E is a point of E

With the following corollary,

> A finite point set has no limit points (pg 33)

This is where I am confused. I have seen examples in topology where finite sets are closed (Take $X = \{ a,b,c\}$ and $\mathcal{T} = \{X, \emptyset,\{a\}, \{a,b\} \} $, here in this example I believe $\{ c \}$ is closed). If I understand correctly, is Rudin saying that in a metric space *no finite sets are closed*? (or is there a contradiction)

Thanks. -

Comment: Thanks, I meant to write $$\{ c\}$$, I'll edit this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it has no limit points, then all limit points belong to the set. This is a vacuous statement. So, Rudin is actually saying that *every* finite set (empty set included) in a metric space is closed.

Comment: thanks! that helps